# Calling synchronous service within JSF ajax refresh

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am trying to call a service that returns a java script which in turns depict Google captcha service. In a regular page refresh, lets say in the footer, the script just works. But i need it just before submit button. The form with submit button is within a content which gets loaded via JSF ajax call. Therefore calling a synchronus service call within an ajax refresh does not work.

The site depicts a page based on state, first it list available forms (xhtml), after clicking one, it loads up that form within the same panel group based on a state which is changed in the bean. The code looks similar to this:

---

```
<h:form id="cm-content-form" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h:panelGroup id="cm-page">
         <h:panelGroup id="cm-panel">
                     <!-- navigation panel-->
                    <h:panelGroup id="cm-nav"> 
                            <div class="row">
                                <h:commandLink value="Home" action="#{cmNavigationBean.navigateHome()}">
                                    <f:ajax render="cm-page"/>
                                </h:commandLink>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <h:commandLink value="Start New Submission" action="#{cmNavigationBean.navigateFormSelect()}">
                                    <f:ajax render="cm-page"/>
                                </h:commandLink>
                            </div>
                            other links
                    </h:panelGroup>
                    <!-- main content panel based on state maintained in managed bean-->
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="cm-content">
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="#{cmNavigationBean.isHomeState()}">
                              <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="cm-content-home">
                                     Welcome to home page.
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="#{cmNavigationBean.isFormSelectState()}">
                                <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="cm-content-form-list">
                                    <h3>Please select the form you wish to submit.</h3>
                                    <hr/>
                                    <c:forEach var="form" items="#{cmNavigationBean.getAllActiveForms()}">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{form.agency.name} - "/><h:commandLink action="#{cmNavigationBean.navigateForm(form.id)}" value="#{form.name}">
                                            <f:ajax render="cm-content"/>
                                        </h:commandLink>
                                        <br/>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when test="#{cmNavigationBean.isFormSubmitState()}">
                                <h:panelGroup id="cm-content-form-submit">  
                                    <c:if test="#{cmFormBean.formsEnabled()}">  
                                        <!-- pasting form here -->
                                        <ui:include src="#{cmFormBean.getCurrentFormURL()}"/>                                         

                                        <!-- captcha goes here -->  
                                        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://oursite.org/captchaservice/generate.htm?userName=aUser">
                                        </script>


                                        <!-- custom control with submit button goes here -->
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <cmi:confirmationPanel
                                                    confirmationPanelTarget="cm-content"
                                                    confirmationPanelText="Please fill out the form above."
                                                    confirmationPanelAcceptButton="Submit"
                                                    confirmationPanelAcceptText="Are you sure you want to submit this form?"
                                                    confirmationPanelAcceptAction="navigateFormSubmit"
                                                    confirmationPanelRejectButton="Cancel"
                                                    confirmationPanelRejectText="Are you sure you want to discard this form?"
                                                    confirmationPanelRejectAction="navigateHome"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </c:if>
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </c:when>

                            </form>
```

...

---

The java script in the example works and show google capthca service panel in a regular page.

```
<script src="https://oursite.org/captchaservice/generate.htm?userName=aUser">
                                        </script>
```

But when I put it within panel group it shows error:

*Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."*

but and when I refresh page in the browser it shows up.

1. I tried to force page refresh from html by using  oncomplete="javascript:location.reload(true)", did not work.
2. I tried to put it in the custom control and try to include during ajax refresh, obviously it was doing the same thing.
3. I tried loading the script during onLoad and try to associate returned data with a `<div>` tag, but getting uncaught exception.

   (function()
   $(document).ready(function() {
           $.get("https://oursite.org/captchaservice/generate.htm", { userName:'aUser' }, function(data, status){
               captcha = data;
           });

   )

then call this function during refresh

```
getCaptcha = function () {
    alert(captcha);
    $('#captcha').html(captcha);
}
```

Althoguh I see contents in the alert dialog, but followed by an empty page.

There should be a simple solution for this which I am not aware of. Can any of  you point me to that direction? Many thanks.

Comment: Please excuse me if primefaces cannot be used in your project  --> http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/captcha.xhtml

Comment: Yeah, I have to use the wrapper service provided by the company. I think easiest way would be force refresh the page from backing bean, but not sure.

Comment: then in 1 try with oncomplete="location.reload();" and let me know

Comment: I moved the script in different place and tried with reload. It works although it reloads the entire page. Lets see if it is acceptable. Thanks for your reply.